# Django project not able to run on mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x, macos-sierra

I just purchased the new 2017 macbook pro. I want to do two things. the first is run a django project and then run my specific file that I have clones from github. I want to pip install django and I am getting a message that pip is not a command.

Every forum is saying that 2017 macbook pro has python 2.X and 3.X I want to set python 3.X as the default.

How can i set python 3 as the default?

what is the command to get pip because when i try to get it from python 2.x and 3.x, it says the file does not exist.

Where and how can I install pip?

I tried installing pip but i was getting a message that it does not exist. how can i go about downloading or getting pip on my mac. I have tried a few different ways and nothing is working. Once i get python and pip, I can install Django and run my django application...

Where and how can i install django framework onto my mac?

Does anyone know how to do this on the OS X sierra for mac.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use python on sierra Mac, but I suggest you to use `brew` to install Python3 and then use `virtualenv` to manage the env of your projects. Don't rely on the default python installed on Sierra.

Install brew is very easy. Just jump here: https://brew.sh/

After that you can install python simply running `brew install python3`

I prefer `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`, but if you want start immediately you can create your env from python3:

```
$ pyvenv myenv
```

And then activate your env

```
$ source myenv/bin/activate
```

Now you can install any package with pip, without changing your system. Run `deactivate` to switch off your env. You can create many envs as you wish and run your app with many different django version.

As I wrote before, I suggest you use `virtualenvwrapper` and `virtualenv`

Comment: So i downloaded homebrew and installed python3. If I wanted to setup a virtualenv, how can i go about doing that instead of creating an environment straight from python3 @KarimNGorjux

Comment: you can follow the instructions here: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i just have to type python3 in all of the commands to run python3 on this mac

Comment: this is related to `brew`. If you run `brew info python` you are able to see the version from brew. Than, if is the version you want to link to the system, just run `brew link python`

Comment: yeah that is how i got it i installed python through brew